# Outlook add-in with global scope (inbox level)

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

Is there a way to have an outlook add-in that uses a global scope? I want to be able to launch the add-in at any time, but not necessarily relate it to a specific e-mail. According to [the documentation I found](https://web.archive.org/web/20170407193719/https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/extensionpoint#extension-points-for-outlook-add-in-commands), the closest thing would be to have it appear as a Module, but then it only works on the desktop version (not the web), and doesn't allow you to view it alongside e-mails. It would be ideal if this could run on the side of the screen, similar to how Skype works on the web version of Outlook, on both the desktop and web versions. Is Skype a special case, or is it possible to build an add-in like that?

Answer (score 1):

Web-based add-ins work in the context of the current item only.

Instead, you may consider developing a browser plug-in which modifies a web page dynamically. And for the desktop editions of Outlook you may consider creating a COM based add-in which allows to customize the UI in the way you need. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started quickly.